# Ошибка при развёртывании контракта в тестовой сети BSC : Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below)

Tags: deploy, ethereum, solidity, smart-contract

При попытке форка SafeMoon в тестовой сети BSC  выходит ошибка при деплое изменённого контракта.
Вот сама ошибка `Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?` 
при по пытке принудительного исполнения выаёт следующее : [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Изменения кода не значительные и не могут вызвать ошибку. в чём может быть причина подобной ошибки ?

Comment: А исходный контракт деплоится нормально?

Comment: @MadJackal при деплое исходного контракта а же ошибка

Comment: Скорее всего кривой конструктор у исходного контракта или параметры конструктора некошерные передаются, если они есть.